# Jquery - Create multiple DOM elements inside a programmatically created parent element

Tags: jquery, html, json, recursion

I'm creating a data-driven list with jquery. I can't figure out how to add multiple children to a parent element using jQuery's method for creating HTML elements. What am I missing here?

I've re-organized the `<a>` elements inside the  so they all can be a new element inside the rendered `<td>`. Instead it every "html" key overwrites the previous key and only the last "html" key and value are rendered. In this case the "a#deleteModal" element is the only one rendered.

This is what I need it to print:

```
<ul class="list-10" style="">
    <li data-info="line91" name="documentationmenunull">
        <table width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdownArrow" data-target="documentationmenu1"><i class="fa fa-minus-square-o"></i></a> 
                        <a href="#" class="editItem" data-target="documentation_1" data-type="Documentation" id="adocumentationmenu1">Main</a> 
                        <a href="#deleteModal"><span class="fa fa-trash-o deleteMenuItem" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Delete"></span></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is how I'm trying to accomplish that:

```
function getList(item, $list) {
  if (item) {
    if (item.title) {
      $list.append($("<li/>", {
        "name": "documentationMenu",
        "html": $("<table/>", {
          "width": "100%",
          "html": $("<tbody/>", {
            "html": $("<tr/>", {
              "html": $("<td/>", {
                "html": $("<a/>", {
                  "href": '#',
                  "data-toggle": "dropdownArrow",
                  "data-target": "documentationMenu" + item.id,
                  "html": $("<i/>", {
                    "class": "fa fa-minus-square-o"
                  }),
                }),
                "html": $("<a/>", {
                  "href": '#',
                  "data-toggle": "dropdownArrow",
                  "data-target": "documentation_" + item.id,
                  "data-type": "documentation",
                  "id": "aDocumentationMenu" + item.id,
                  "html": item.title
                }),
                "html": $("<a/>", {
                  "href": '#deleteModal',
                  "html": $("<span/>", {
                    "class": "fa fa-trash-o deleteMenuItem",
                    "data-toggle": "tooltip",
                    "title": "Delete"
                  })
                })
              })
            })
          })
        })
      }));
    }
    if (item.children) {
      var $sublist = $("<ul/>");
      $.each(item.children, function(key, value) {
        getList(value, $sublist);
      });
      $list.append($sublist);
    }
  }
}
```

Essentially you can ignore the last if block for item.children. I just need to figure out how to place several anchor tags inside the `<td>`. Any ideas?

Comment: Just because you can do something, doesn't mean you should.  In this case, the use of repeated nestings of 'html' applies.  This is highly unreadable, and thus a potential maintenance nightmare.  Templating libraries are your friend.

Comment: Or potentially using a template literal (ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) would make this much much easier to maintain and read.

Comment: It's a valid point you make, and yes, it does look a little convoluted from the outside. Personally, I love jquery's ability to make DOM elements like this... and I posted here bc I thought others might also like it. If there is a way to do what I am trying to do, it would be really nice to do it. I was hoping to find someone who knew more about this method than I. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: Also please don't use the `<table>` tag for anything other than tabular data. It serves no purpose here.

Comment: @JonP, I totally agree. Unfortunately I did not design this code... and the budget for this task may not allow for clean up of the HTML and CSS also tied to this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end @Taplar had the suggestion for the appropriate solution. I had hoped to find a solution that worked with the code I shared originally which documentation can be found here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2.
Unfortunately it appears to be a code style that hasn't drawn the right person's attention or it's not widely liked. Here's a quick rundown of what I went with using a template literal.

```
<div id="documentationMenuList"></div>

<script>
function buildMenu(menu_items, name){
    var $ul = $('<ul class="list-10"></ul>');

    $.each(menu_items, function (key, value) {
        createCollapsableList(value, $ul, name);
    });

    $ul.appendTo("#"+name+"MenuList");
}

function createCollapsableList(item, $collapsableList, name) {
    if (item) {     
        if (item.title) {
            $collapsableList.append(
            `<li name="${name}Menu${item.parent_id ? item.parent_id : 0}">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdownArrow" data-target="${name}Menu${item.id}"><i class="fa fa-minus-square-o"></i></a> 
                                <a href="#" class="editItem" data-target="${name}_${item.id}" data-type="${name}" id="${name}Menu${item.id}">${item.title}</a> 
                                <a href="#deleteModal"><span class="fa fa-trash-o deleteMenuItem" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"></span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </li>`);
        }
        if (item.children) {
            var $sublist = $('<ul class="list-10"></ul>');
            $.each(item.children, function (key, value) {
                createCollapsableList(value, $sublist);
            });
            $collapsableList.append($sublist);
        }
    }
}
$(function(){
    buildMenu(menu_items, 'documentation');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Most of us like to simplify things to make them more maintainable, which is probably why you haven't had much traction with your original approach. One suggestion I have for what you have here is to use a [Document Fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) like I have in my answer. The reason is every time you `append` to the DOM it causes a redraw and this can get expensive. Append to the fragment, then append the fragment to the DOM once.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of avoiding putting HTML into my JavaScript. If I'm changing layout, I want to work with HTML and CSS, not javascript.

Make a template in your HTML, clone it, populate the clone and append it. We'll also use a doumentFragment so we don't repeatly update the DOM causing redraws.

```js
var listItems = [{id: 1, title: "Main"}, {id:101, title: "Yellow Submarine"}];


function generateList(items, listElement) {
  //Set Up Template
  var s = $("#listItem")[0].innerHTML.trim(); 
  var holder = document.createElement('div');
  holder.innerHTML = s;
  var template = holder.childNodes;

  //Create doucument fragment 
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  
  //iterate the items
  items.forEach(function(item){
    //console.log(item)
    //Clone the template
    var newItem = $(template).clone();    
    //UPdate the data 
    newItem.html(newItem.html()
      .replace(/{{id}}/g, item.id)
      .replace(/{{title}}/g, item.title));
      //console.log(newItem.html());
    //Append to the fragment
    $(frag).append(newItem);
  }) ;

  //Append the fragment to the list
  $(listElement).append(frag);
}

generateList(listItems, $(".list-10"));
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-10" style="">    
</ul>

<template id="listItem">
    <li data-info="line91" name="documentationmenunull">
        <div>           
          <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdownArrow" data-target="documentationmenu{{id}}"><i class="fa fa-minus-square-o"></i></a> 
          <a href="#" class="editItem" data-target="documentation_{{id}}" data-type="Documentation" id="adocumentationmenu{{id}}">{{title}}</a> 
          <a href="#deleteModal"><span class="fa fa-trash-o deleteMenuItem" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Delete"></span></a>
          </div>
      </li>
</template>
```

Comment: While I appreciate your opinion, and knowledge, it doesn't at all fit as a solution to my challenge. I do like your use of templates though and find that a cool idea where it fits. I'm not familiar with the use of the template tag. Does the browser CSS always hide `<template>` elements?

Comment: `<template>` hides every thing in it. The downside is that it is not supported in IE, but you can use `<script type="template">` in a similar fashion with a couple of minor tweaks to the code.