# Display object value inside an array into HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I created an array of objects:

```js
let games = [{
    title: 'God of War',
    price: 50,
    img: "./assets/images/God-of-War.jpg"
  },
  {
    title: 'Death Stranding',
    price: 70,
    img: "./assets/images/Death-Stranding.jpg"
  },
  {
    title: 'The Last Of Us 2',
    price: 40,
    img: "./assets/images/The-Last-Of-Us-2.jpg"
  }
];
```

```html
<h1>Games</h1>
<div>
  <div>
    <h2>
      <script>
        games[0].title
      </script>
    </h2>
    <button>Buy</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I want to display all of them as if they were in an E-Commerce website,
but I can't display the values in my HTML.
 This is my HTML code:

Comment: What **specifically** do you mean by “as if they were in a E-Commerce website”? Why **exactly** can you not display the values in your HTML?

Comment: I want to make a <div> showing the img of the "game", right below the title and the price alongside.

Comment: @ViníciusCardoso So what is the problem? What have you tried? Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre].

Comment: I tried to call the game[0].title inside the HTML and it didn't work.

Comment: `game`? Your variable is called `games`. What do you mean by “call”? You don’t have any function to call. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: You might want to read up on how to access html elements using javascript. Your approach simply will not work. Accessing HTML elements is also known as accessing and manipulating the DOM (Document Object Model)

Comment: Two upvotes.... o_O Really

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not sure what you are trying to do but see if this helps at all. That's my take on what I think you're trying to accomplish:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <title>Vini Game Store</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Games</h1>
    <div id = "game1"></br>
    <div id = "game2"></br>
    <div id = "game3">

    <script>
    let games = [];//array goes here

    var game1 = document.getElementById('game1');
    var game2 = document.getElementById('game2');
    var game3 = document.getElementById('game3');

    game1.innerHTML = games[0].title + ', price:' + games[0].price;
    game2.innerHTML = games[1].title + ', price:' + games[1].price;
    game3.innerHTML = games[2].title + ', price:' + games[2].price;
    </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going with a simplified version of [what I would normally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57685465/4665) do as I sense you are new to javascript.

I'm a fan of keeping HTML and javascript separate. Normally I would create a template in the HTML, clone it and work with that. I would also normally use a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) so I  would only be updating the DOM once.

To keep thinks simple I'm going to use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and skip the document fragment

```js
var games = [{
    title: 'God of War',
    price: 50,
    img: "./assets/images/God-of-War.jpg"
  },
  {
    title: 'Death Stranding',
    price: 70,
    img: "./assets/images/Death-Stranding.jpg"
  },
  {
    title: 'The Last Of Us 2',
    price: 40,
    img: "./assets/images/The-Last-Of-Us-2.jpg"
  }
];

function buildGames(parent, games) {
  var html = "";
  games.forEach(function(game) {
    //Set Our Itemp template
    let itemTemplate = `
  <li>
     <h2>${game.title}</h2>
     <div class="price">Price: $ ${game.price}</div>
     <img src="${game.img}" alt="Image of ${game.title}" />
  </li>`;
    //update the html 
    html += itemTemplate
  });
  //Update the parent once
  parent.innerHTML += html;
}

buildGames(document.getElementById("gamesList"), games);
```

```css
#gamesList {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#gamesList li {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #333;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Games</h1>
<ul id="gamesList">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through your array with JavaScript's `forEach`:

```js
let games = [{
    title: 'God of War',
    price: 50,
    img: "./assets/images/God-of-War.jpg"
  },
  {
    title: 'Death Stranding',
    price: 70,
    img: "./assets/images/Death-Stranding.jpg"
  },
  {
    title: 'The Last Of Us 2',
    price: 40,
    img: "./assets/images/The-Last-Of-Us-2.jpg"
  }
];

function displayGames() {
  var result = '';
 games.forEach(function(game) {
    result += '<div class="item col-sm-4"><h2>' + game.title + '</h2><div><img class="img-fluid" src="' + game.img + '"></div><p class="text-right">' + game.price + '</p></div></div>';
});

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = result;

}

displayGames();
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="container" class="row"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your best option is to iterate the `games` object:

```js
let games = [{
    title: 'God of War',
    price: 50,
    img: "./assets/images/God-of-War.jpg"
  },
  {
    title: 'Death Stranding',
    price: 70,
    img: "./assets/images/Death-Stranding.jpg"
  },
  {
    title: 'The Last Of Us 2',
    price: 40,
    img: "./assets/images/The-Last-Of-Us-2.jpg"
  }
];

function makeTable() {
  var results = '';
  var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
  var tableBody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
    results += '<tr><td>' + games[i].title + '</td><td>' + games[i].price + '</td><td><img src="' + games[i].img + '"></td></tr>';
  }


  tableBody.innerHTML = results;

}


makeTable();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered my-2" id="dataTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Image</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```